# stable gazebo version and best gazebo version?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Which gazebo version is stable and which one is best? As i saw that in gazebo 9 so many physics classes memebers has been removed like get angle, set angle. So if i 'm using gazebo 9 how should i get the angles and set angles of a particular joint?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18555/stable-gazebo-version--and-best-gazebo-version?/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

"Best" is a bit too general; it all depends on your use case, the system you're working on, which integrations you need, etc.

The latest stable release is Gazebo 9. That is a long-term-support version and will be supported until 2023. You can check [here](http://gazebosim.org/#status) for other versions.

For the functions that "disappeared", you can search the [Migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo9/Migration.md) for the replacement.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2018-02-19**:
ok. thanks, i'm really enjoying learning this simulator.